# How do I filter a list within a list while maintaining the original form of the object using linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a List and each school object has a List. A Student has gender M or F.
What I would like to do is to get a list of Schools that have students with gender M.
**I would like to maintain the object format** ( list within a list) so **SelectMany**  I suppose won't work here because it flattens out the structure.

```
public class School 
{  
  private string name;  
  private string address;  
  private IList<Student> students;  
}  

public class Student  
{  
   private string name;  
   private int age;  
   private char gender;  
}
```

Note: This is just an exemplary structure.

Comment: Wouldn't Any() only validate if exists at least one Student with gender M and if the condition is true bring all of them regardless of being M or F ? I would only want to get back the M, so it would be like removing anything that doesn't match gender == M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var maleSchools = schools
    .Select(s => new School { name = s.name, address = s.address, students = s.students.Where(stud => stud.gender == 'M').ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

As far I understand your question, it will be simply:

```
var result = schools.Where(school => school.Students
                                           .Any(student => student.Gender == 'M'));
```

Then of course you can do `result.ToList()` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to reform the objects, and that will quickly get out of hand if the objects are more complex.

This is much easier and cleaner if you look for schools Where( Any(student is male) )

```
var maleSchools = schools.Where(school => school.students.Any(student => student.gender == 'M'))
```

To answer your comment of getting the "students" property of School to only show male students, I see three non-messy ways, listed in order of preference.

One - do the filtering when you use that collection - a simple Where clause to filter to only males. (Might not be feasible, not knowing your use case - read on.)

Two, create a type that contains the unmodified School, but alongside all of its male students:

```
var maleStudents = schools.Select(school => {
    School = school, 
    MaleStudents = school.students.Where(student => student.gender == 'M') 
});
```

Three, add a property, method, or extension method to School that surfaces the already-filtered collection you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
var q = 
    from s in schools
    where s.students.Any(st => st.gender == 'M')
    select s;
```

Do I miss something? You are not saying you want to filter out students, just that you want schools with M only students. So it should work.

BTW, you members are private, which of course has to be changed.